# Cannot resolve symbol 'jackson' while importing apache camel org.apache.camel.component.jackson.JacksonDataFormat

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, apache-camel

This is how I added it to my pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-jackson-starter</artifactId>
      <version>${camel.version}</version>
      <!-- use the same version as your Camel core version -->
    </dependency>
```

I also tried the non spring version of adding it to my pom, but got the same error

Comment: Have you tried refreshing your maven dependencies, cleaning language workspace or just restarting your IDE?  What Camel version are you using with what JDK?

Comment: I just had to invalidate caches and restart the ide and it works now. I can't believe that's all it was lol. Thank you

Comment: @CrisManrique You really should never have to use that evil button in IntelliJ unless something is really wrong. Are you sure you refreshed the Maven project? When you edit the POM file, you should see a little button appear in the top-right of the editor. You can also refresh using the Maven toolbar.